# Issue with Lollipop upgrade on Micromax Yureka: calling interface

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, micromax-yu-yureka, call-recording

I could not record the call while I'm talking. To record, I need to go to many options before recording the call. It was good in kitkat and to record the call with one button click. And the interface of the calling is not good in Lollipop.

Comment: So you're referring to in-built call recorder of Android is the issue for you. Right! Will it be problematic if an automatic call recording app is used, no need to tap button. https://play.google.com/store/search?q=call%20recorder&c=apps&hl=en  About the interface, why not use an app like Truedialer or Hello which have nice good interface. Would be it  good or you don't want to use an external app at all?

Comment: @Firelord, sometimes the in-call UI is set to the default one in many Indian devices, and however hard one tried, they can't change it.

Comment: So, have you tried using 3rd party apps to solve your problem ? As @Firelord mentioned, try using apps like Truedialer / Facebook Hello to bypass your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Call recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder&hl=en). I'm using Yureka and have upgraded to v5.0 and it works, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Galaxy Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oduzhar.galaxycallrecorder) app to record both sides of call for Yureka running Lollipop. I've tried it. Other recorders don't records both sides of call.